# Java network transfer large amount data

Tags: java, networking

i am recently working on multiplayer client/server typing game for 3 players. Now i am sending `3xboolean`, `double`, `2xint` and `long`. I want to ask if is possible to somehow pack the data and send just the data packet.

Comment: You may wrap these inside an Object, and use Object(Input/Output)Stream .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing the actual object to the network I would recomend serializing it to a stable format (JSON for example) and sending that. The receiving end would get the JSON from the socket and decode to an object. Here is a quick example of what you need (I used [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson) for Json parsing)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    //Sender side
    Message message = new Message();
    message.setA(true);
    message.setD("Hello World");

    String messageAsJson = gson.toJson(message);
    //write messageAsJson to socket
    System.out.println(messageAsJson);



    //Receiver side, reads line from socket and decodes
    Message decodedMessage = gson.fromJson(messageAsJson, Message.class);
    System.out.println(decodedMessage.getA());
    System.out.println(decodedMessage.getD());
}


public static class Message {
    private Boolean a;
    private String d;
    public Boolean getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(Boolean a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String getD() {
        return d;
    }
    public void setD(String d) {
        this.d = d;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this example. You have to create a Class with following fields

> 3xboolean, double, 2xint and long

and use transport approach provided here --> 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html